# OSX (Yosemite) file permissions on files written to SMB-shares

Tags: macos, permissions, samba, smb

In my workplace we work with a big SMB-share on which all files are saved.

Files saved by windows machines by default have `-rw-rw----` as permissions and all folders come with `drwxrwx---`.

However the files written from OSX (Yosemite) machines have `-rw--w----`. This is a problem since it means that other team members can not view those files.

Is it possible to set the default permission for files written by OSX on the SMB-share to 0660? Right now I fix this manually through the terminal everytime I write a file, but that leaves a lot of room for user error (i.e. forgetting to change the permission).

I'm already running SMBUp, but sadly this has not fixed the issue.

EDIT: preferably without changing serverside settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the share is managed via the Server app, enable ACL's on the server, and configure the share through the Server app adding a group that all the team members are in and giving them read/write access.

I had a similar problem in the past and chmod/chown/chgrp simply didn't cut it.

edit: Forgot to mention you'll also need to enable inheritance permissions when setting this so that when new files are created, the same permissions are enabled on these files/folders.

Comment: Ah yes, that could be an option. But I'd have to take that up with our IT-supplier. I would prefer to be able to do this without changing settings on the server.

Comment: Thanks for you response, to bad it isn't possible to fix this client side.

Answer (score 1):

You really should set it up on the server as it is the most correct way:

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203574

That said, setting inheritable ACLs from a client is often possible.

Otherwise disabling UNIX extensions on all the OS X clients may work:

[How to keep group-writeable shares on Samba with OSX clients?](https://superuser.com/questions/675936/how-to-keep-group-writeable-shares-on-samba-with-osx-clients)

Answer (score -1):

Super late to the party here, but I think I've cracked this without needing server-side changes (which our sysadmins weren't willing to do just to accommodate my Mac when everyone else's Macs / Linux / Windows boxes were working fine).

For me it was just images which were the issue. After much investigating I finally realised it was only images downloaded from my browser (Chrome).

So from Chrome, if I drag an image to my desktop, and then upload to SMB it ends up with no 'read' permission for 'everyone'

If from Chrome right click > save as > desktop/filename.jpg and then copy to the SMB in the same way, everything is fine

So it is a Chrome / Mac permission thing, rather than a Mac / SMB thing. Barking up the wrong tree entirely blaming the SMB. That took me hours to figure out.

Edit: Here is the issue raised on Google forums https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/M2mkWaslmRA